# how to parse a rgbColor using c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble parsing a RGB color. I need the int values in there own variable.

here is a screenshot of what the object looks like
[image: screenshot]

I need to end up with this

data

[0]

R = int value

G = int value

B = int value

Name = string value

Each object has 2 properties, Name, Color. the color value is a RGB color, rgb(67,134,215)

I need to recreate the object to look like

Name = value,

R = 67,

G = 134,

B = 215

Comment: This is very simple have you tried anything ?

Comment: yes, i just posted what I am trying

Comment: That is 2 different things. What have you tried to parse the rgb(67,134,215) into the desired form ?

Comment: You're assigning c.R to G and B. Is that a copy and paste error?

Comment: I do not know what to search for. I am finding nothing but parsing RGB colors to hex values

Comment: yes, just corrected it

Comment: How about looking up how to parse a string ? string.Split is a good place to start.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "parse". Are you saying you have a string that looks like `"item.data = rgb(67,134,215)"`?

Comment: What is the problem with that last code block?  Doesn't that do exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: i just updated the question. i should have been more clear

Comment: what do you want to have? a function which converts `67,134,215` to a color or a element which stores the color integers? what is your input e.g a string with or without `rgb(...)`? what is your supposed output?

Comment: see update,  i added pic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily accomplished with Regex:

```
string colorStr = "rgb(67,134,215)";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"rgb\((?<r>\d{1,3}),(?<g>\d{1,3}),(?<b>\d{1,3})\)");
Match match = regex.Match(colorStr);
if (match.Success)
{
    int r = int.Parse(match.Groups["r"].Value);
    int g = int.Parse(match.Groups["g"].Value);
    int b = int.Parse(match.Groups["b"].Value);

    //// Create your new object with the r, g, b values
}
```